# Turtle doing nothing in embedded Tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-turtle, python-class

I am trying to make a program in which you can draw different shapes. I already managed to embed the turtlescreen into my already existing Tkinter one (root) and got a Tkinter Menu, in which I can run the different commands to draw my shapes.

This is my problem: If you click on any of the shapes in the "Shapes" Menu, nothing will happen. The turtle will just sit somewhere on the screen, not doing anything. I don't get any errorcodes or something like that and it should work just fine. But still, it doesn't.

Probably, I'm just blind and tired (I am working on this code for almost 5 hours non-stop) but I want to fix this error. So, if it's in plain sight, I am sorry.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle as t
import math
from tkinter import Menu
import ctypes

title = "Turtle printer"
button_width = 30
hypotenuse = 100
cathete = hypotenuse / math.sqrt(2)


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.setup_root()

    def setup_root(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        self.root.title(title)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.turtle_screen = t.TurtleScreen(self.canvas)
        self.turtle_screen._RUNNING = True  # Reactivate

        self.turtle = t.RawTurtle(self.turtle_screen)

        self.setup_turtle_screen()

        self.setup_file_menu()
        self.setup_shape_menu()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def exit_root(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        self.root.quit()

    def setup_file_menu(self):
        menu = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=menu)
        filemenu = Menu(menu)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.exit_root)

    def setup_shape_menu(self):
        menu = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=menu)
        shapemenu = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Shapes", menu=shapemenu)
        shapemenu.add_command(label="F", command=self.draw_f_shape)
        shapemenu.add_command(label="Square", command=self.draw_square)
        # Add more shape commands here

    def setup_turtle_screen(self):
        user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
        screen_width = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)
        screen_height = user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)

        self.canvas.config(width=screen_width, height=screen_height)
        self.turtle_screen.screensize(screen_width, screen_height)
        self.turtle_screen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height)
        self.turtle_screen.tracer(0)

# Add shape drawing commands below

    def draw_f_shape(self):
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.goto(0, 0)
        self.turtle.pendown()

        self.turtle.left(90)
        self.turtle.forward(90)
        self.turtle.right(90)
        self.turtle.color("red")
        self.turtle.forward(60)
        self.turtle.back(60)

        self.turtle.left(90)
        self.turtle.color("black")
        self.turtle.forward(60)
        self.turtle.left(90)
        self.turtle.color("red")
        self.turtle.back(100)

        self.turtle.reset()
        self.turtle_screen.update()

    def draw_square(self):
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.goto(0, 0)
        self.turtle.pendown()

        for _ in range(4):
            self.turtle.forward(100)
            self.turtle.right(90)

        self.turtle.reset()
        self.turtle_screen.update()

Main()
```

I tried to draw a shape, it should've sent the turtle to the center, and it should've started drawing, but it just sat somewhere on the screen without moving. I didn't really try anything except for looking through the code multiple times. I don't really know, what I should change.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your combined use of `tracer(0)`, `reset`, and `update`.

`tracer(0)` means you can't watch the turtle draw.  Changes are all queued up until an `update` call.  `reset` erases the screen.  So, by the time `update` gets called, all of your drawing has been erased.

Delete the `reset` calls, and you will have happiness.

Comment: This is a good case where a "divide and conquer" minimization strategy might have helped OP--remove each line one by one to try to isolate the problem, or a "build it back up line by line" strategy, both described in [mcve] and [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Given that OP presumably only wrote about half dozen lines of code and most of this is provided boilerplate, this should be pretty effective.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a Mac right now, so I had to change the code to be universal– despite the beauty of Python's universality, `ctypes` isn't too friendly. Thus, the first change I made was how the screen size was calculated (using `TKinter`), though this was not a cure to the problem.

As Tim said, you are resetting your own drawing. If you get rid of it, you can  actually see what is drawn. Here is what I ultimately got working for me:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter import Tk
import turtle as t
import math


title = "Turtle printer"
button_width = 30
hypotenuse = 100
cathete = hypotenuse / math.sqrt(2)



class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.setup_root()

    def setup_root(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        self.root.title(title)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.turtle_screen = t.TurtleScreen(self.canvas)
        self.turtle_screen._RUNNING = True  # Reactivate

        self.turtle = t.RawTurtle(self.turtle_screen)

        self.setup_turtle_screen()

        self.setup_file_menu()
        self.setup_shape_menu()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def exit_root(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        self.root.quit()

    def setup_file_menu(self):
        menu = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=menu)
        filemenu = Menu(menu)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.exit_root)

    def setup_shape_menu(self):
        menu = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=menu)
        shapemenu = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Shapes", menu=shapemenu)
        shapemenu.add_command(label="F", command=self.draw_f_shape)
        shapemenu.add_command(label="Square", command=self.draw_square)


    def setup_turtle_screen(self):
        screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth() # Note that this method is universal across platforms
        screen_height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()

        self.canvas.config(width=screen_width, height=screen_height)
        self.turtle_screen.screensize(screen_width, screen_height)
        self.turtle_screen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height)
        self.turtle_screen.tracer(0)



    def setup_turtle_screen(self):
        screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()

        self.canvas.config(width=screen_width, height=screen_height)
        self.turtle_screen.screensize(screen_width, screen_height)
        self.turtle_screen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height)
        self.turtle_screen.tracer(0)


    def draw_f_shape(self):
        start_x = self.root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2
        start_y = self.root.winfo_screenheight() / 2
        
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.goto(start_x, start_y)
        self.turtle.pendown()

        self.turtle.left(90)
        self.turtle.forward(90)
        self.turtle.right(90)
        self.turtle.color("red")
        self.turtle.forward(60)
        self.turtle.back(60)

        self.turtle.left(90)
        self.turtle.color("black")
        self.turtle.forward(60)
        self.turtle.left(90)
        self.turtle.color("red")
        self.turtle.back(100)

        # self.turtle.reset() We can see our shape now!
        self.turtle_screen.update()

    def draw_square(self):
        start_x = self.root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2
        start_y = self.root.winfo_screenheight() / 2
        
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.goto(start_x, start_y)
        self.turtle.pendown()

        for _ in range(4):
            self.turtle.forward(100)
            self.turtle.right(90)

        # self.turtle.reset()  We comment this out so we can see our shape!
        self.turtle_screen.update()

Main()
`
```